# Extract a pattern using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string variable and want to extract year and number alone.

```
$val = '2015(15)';
preg_match ('/(.*?)\((.*?)\)/',$val,$match);
print_r($match);
```

Output: `Array ( [0] => 2015(15) [1] => 2015 [2] => 15 )`

Expected: the above is ok. or `Array ( [0] => 2015 [1] => 15 )`

```
$val = '2015';
preg_match ('/(.*?)\((.*?)\)/',$val,$match);
print_r($match);
```

Output: `Array ( )`

Expected: `Array ( [0] => 2015 [1] =>  )`

```
$val = '(15)';
preg_match ('/(.*?)\((.*?)\)/',$val,$match);
print_r($match);
```

Output: `Array ( [0] => (15) [1] => [2] => 15 )`

Expected: `Array ( [0] => [1] => 15 )`

Comment: Can't you just explode with `)` and remove the final `)` from the second item? There are other non-regex ways.

Comment: Yes. I can use split or explode and trim the result array last index with ')'. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Perhaps you can try something like,

```
/([0-9]{4})?(?:\(([0-9]*)\))?/
```

Comment: if talking about year number then `([12][0-9]{3})` is a bit more realistic, even consider the abbreviation two number form how to converted back to 4, if only years after 2000 count then `(2[0-9]{3})`

Comment: Thank you. This way I can achieve my expected result.

Comment: @cske That is perfectly acceptable but also makes the code obsolete after 2999.  Realistically, there's no reason not to accept years 0000 to 9999 and the reason why I restrict years tightly to 4 numbers is because of what the OP had provided.

Comment: i mean real life, not some academic propouse , i don't think is happyy path for OP to match eq. `0001`

Comment: @cske That is unfortunate.